# passing "this" as an argument

Tags: javascript, this

I'm a pretty new web developer learning html5 and javascript.

I have a webpage with "tabs" that make parts of the webpage disappear and reappear.

The links are like this:

```
<a href="?tab=1" id="t1" class="tab" onclick="switchf('Home',this)">HOME</a>
```

and the javascript function `switchf()` is like this:

```
function switchf(field,tab) {
    var divs = ["Home","About","Chatroom","Account","Contact","Signup"];
    for(var j = 0; j < divs.length; j++) {
        if(field != divs[j])
            document.getElementById(divs[j]).style.display = "none";
        else
            document.getElementById(divs[j]).style.display = "block";
    }

    var t = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
    for(var i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
        t[i].style.backgroundColor = "#dddddd";
    }

    tab.style.backgroundColor = "#cccccc";
    document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML = field;
}
```

It takes two arguments - the part of the page to appear and the tab that was pressed.

It loops through the parts of the page and changes them all to `display="none"`, then goes to all the tabs and changes them to `backgroundColor="#dddddd"`.

Then it chooses the right tab to change color and the right part of the page to appear.

However, when I am passing `this` as an argument (`onclick="switchf('Home',this)"`), it doesn't change color (`tab.style.backgroundColor = "#cccccc";`).

Is this the right way to pass `this` as an argument? I figured it would be the easiest way - but I've never used it in js before and it doesn't work in this example.

Like all my other mistakes, it's probably a very simple one, but please point it out to me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're following the `href`, which refreshes the page. Add `return false` to the inline handler to prevent this.

```
<a href="?tab=1" id="t1" class="tab" onclick="switchf('Home',this); return false;">HOME</a>
```

---

Or just add `return` before the function call, and then `return false` inside the function.

```
<a href="?tab=1" id="t1" class="tab" onclick="return switchf('Home',this);">HOME</a>
```

```
function switchf(field,tab) {
    var divs = ["Home","About","Chatroom","Account","Contact","Signup"];
    for(var j = 0; j < divs.length; j++) {
        if(field != divs[j])
            document.getElementById(divs[j]).style.display = "none";
        else
            document.getElementById(divs[j]).style.display = "block";
    }

    var t = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
    for(var i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
        t[i].style.backgroundColor = "#dddddd";
    }

    tab.style.backgroundColor = "#cccccc";
    document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML = field;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: it still seems to reload the page.

Comment: @Jon: If you modified the code correctly, it'll only reload the page if the JavaScript fails sometime before the `return false;`. Check your browser's developer console for errors.

Comment: i just figured out there was an error that read "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null" in the javascript on this line: `document.getElementById(divs[j]).style.display = "none";` what does this mean?

Comment: @Jon: This means there's no element on the page with the ID provided by `divs[j]`. Check the spelling of the IDs in your document and Array.

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, `this` refers to the object that contains the event handler attribute.

`this` is one of the most useful features of JavaScript, and using it in the manner shown in your question is exactly what it was designed for. The other function that is run by the event handler can thereby receive the object as one of its arguments.

I am looking through your code to see what else may be happening with it.

Update: Your event handler is not stopping the link from submitting, meaning that your page will be reloaded with the query string that you specified.

You have two options now:

1. return `false` in your event handler to prevent the link from being followed and the page refreshed. **Like this:**
   `onclick="switchf('Home',this); return false;"`
2. allow the link to be followed and change your event handler to a query-string parser that changes the active tab based on the current query string. (This solution would be preferred because it would allow visitors to view a specific tab directly from an external link without needing to follow the link to your site and then secondarily click on a certain tab.)

P.S. Here is some code of mine that does virtually the exact same thing and uses the same arguments as the code you posted:

http://jsfiddle.net/cookies/4JPJA/2/

Comment: the first suggestion doesn't seem to work. can you please elaborate on the second option?

Comment: @Jon it looks right except that you are including an `href` in your link. What probably is happening is that for an instant the menu is updated but then immediately the page is refreshed and you will see the previous menu again.

Comment: Sure, just post your code at http://jsfiddle.net and click "Save" and then post me the resulting URL in a comment. I can update your code with query string reader with no problem.

Comment: It looks like you already have a query string reader in there that calls `switchf` with the appropriate field. And it looks like @user2736012 was able to answer all your questions. But if you need anything further, don't hesitate to ask!